# Which digital cameras are using which sensors?

Tags: sensor, sony

I was surprised to learn from https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/3434/4795 that Sony built sensors are used by a few major camera manufacutrers (eg. Nikon, Pentax...)

Does anyone have a list or a link to a list of all the current non-Sony branded (eg. Nikon, Pentax) cameras that are actually using Sony sensors?

UPDATE: As suggested by the first response perhaps this should be a CW of all Sensor/Camera pairings.

Comment: I've locked this question because it's a very poor fit for the site. Unless there's a dedicated effort to maintain, this list will become out of date and not very useful, so it's basically historically interesting and that's all. Please discuss in meta if you'd like to see this unlocked again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we should change this question to a Community Wiki with a list of Cameras and the Sensors used.

## Aptina Sensors

- Nikon V1/J1

## Canon Sensors

All Canon DSLRs

## DALSA Sensors

Phase One Digital Backs

## Nikon Sensors

**NC81366W**

- Nikon D4

**NC81361A**

- Nikon D3s

**NC81338L**

- Nikon D700
- Nikon D3

**NC81362A**

- Nikon 3100

**NC81369R**

- Nikon 3200

## Truesense Imaging (Formerly Kodak Image Sensor Solutions & Platinum Equity)

**KAF-40000**

- Pentax 645D

Early Hasselblad backs?
Leica M9/M9-P/M9 Monochrome, Leica S2
Early Phase One digital backs

## Sony Sensors

**IMX094AQP**

- Nikon D800/D800E

**ICX453**

- Nikon D40
- Nikon D50
- Nikon D70

**ICX493aqa**

- Nikon D3000
- Nikon D60
- Nikon D40x
- Nikon D80

**IMX021**

- Nikon D300

**IMX038**
 12 MP (4288 x 2848)

- Nikon D90      (2008)
- Nikon D5000    (2009)
- Nikon D300s    (2009)
- Pentax K-r     (2010)
- Fuji X100      (2010)

**IMX071**

- Nikon 5100
- Nikon 7000
- Fuji X-Pro1
- Pentax K-5
- Pentax K-01
- Pentax K-30
- Sony a580
- Sony A55, Sony NEX-5N, Fuji X-Pro1
- Sony NEX-5N
- Fuji X-Pro 1

## STMicroelectronics Sensors

Probable sensor in upcoming Leica S3