# Switching gear from Canon to Sony

Tags: canon, sony

I been on Canon gear for more that 5+ year and mostly shoot with 5DIII,  got wide range of Canon lenses.

Thinking of switching to mirrorless camera and been reading a lot on Sony and using Canon lenses with adaptor on Sony.

I think there are lots of them who have gone through this process and would like to know there experiences ... is it worth spending $$$ to get new Sony gear or stick with canon gear and upgrade newer canon versions.

Comment: If there is a way to reframe this to be more objective...please do it. As is, it’s pretty opinion based and there are a myriad of forums already discussing it

Comment: eehm...what is the question in here?

Comment: Related: [What should I do to switch my gear from Sony to Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3433/what-should-i-do-to-switch-my-gear-from-sony-to-canon)

Comment: We can't answer "is it worth it" for you.

Comment: You never said _why_ you are considering switching from Canon to (Sony) mirrorless, which I think is an important point to be able to articulate.

Comment: Why are you considering a switch? What photographic problem do you want to solve that you think switching to Sony will answer?

Answer (score 5):

Don't.

All those youtubers you've been watching are either directly or indirectly sponsored by Sony. Don't buy into the hype. If you were to buy a new system, you could just go Sony. But switching "just because", makes absolutely no sense.

Don't buy into the hype of pixel peepers (Tony Northrup being a big offender here). The guy had a video about how "tests" showed Canon to be sharper at the edges than Nikon. Seriously, NO ONE cares about that, DO NOT buy that hype.

Stick with your system and enjoy it. Glass is forever, but sony puts out a new A7 model every 6 months and youtube is boiling with people claiming it's SO MUCH BETTER than the older model. It's not ("LOL", they removed the intervalometer feature from the A7R3!)

Eventually Canon will catch up to Sony and you'll be able to use your precious glass on a proper Canon camera without losing any functionality to adapters.

Comment: With Firmware 3.0 the interval function has been brought back to both the a7RIII and the a7III in February 2019 - so that claim is false.

Comment: @KaiMattern the fact that they put it back doesn't change that they removed it.

Comment: If you want to play it that way around...

Comment: @KaiMattern let's put it another way: I never had to "upgrade" firmwares in a DSLR before. Sony has firmware 3.0 already. Should we expect bad quality, untested code? "We'll fix in on the next release"? Come on.

Comment: Firmware updates are a good thing. They brought a ton of new features, adding support for newer lenses and fixing bugs and quirks. Better AF, Animal Eye AF among other stuff. As a software developer, I can say: There is no reasonable complex code without bugs.And that is no difference with Canon and Nikon. 
The only company adding more features (at least that I owned a cam from) was Fuji.
Or are you of the type that also never installs an update to your phone or computer OS?

Answer (score 4):

Being a Sony shooter, I urge you not to listen into hype. And the Sony is a hyped system. As with every tool, the Sony cams have their strong points as well as their weaknesses.

You could use your Canon glass on a Sigma MC-11 Adapter. But the results will vary. Some lenses work well, some don't.

If you really consider the step, I would propose to rent a Sony and the MC-11 and try the cam for a weekend. That might cost you 200 bucks, but it might save you a lot money - or help you to know why you are switching.

Speaking only for myself, I found that the Sony a7 III has helped me becoming a better portrait photographer, as the focus system really minimizes out of focus shots. The battery power is good and I never ran out of power in a shooting from a single battery. But I also dislike the mediocre EVF and the menu structure.

There is no perfect camera - there is only the best camera for YOU. And only YOU can find that for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> ... is it worth spending $$$ to get new Sony gear or stick with canon gear and upgrade newer canon versions.

That is something you will have to decide for yourself.

Since you have a "wide range of Canon lenses", you'll likely encounter a "wide range" of issues if you attempt to adapt them to a non-Canon system, especially if any of your lenses are older designs or third-party models.

Using adapters can be a good way to expand lens selection or ease the transition to a new system if you need to use only a select few lenses that are known to be compatible.

Otherwise, have you considered continuing to use what you have while the Canon R system matures?

> Thinking of switching to mirrorless camera and been reading a lot on Sony and using Canon lenses with adaptor on Sony.

- What are you expecting a Sony body to do that your Canon camera does not? Why switch to Sony rather than another system?

  If you have no need to switch systems, you'll be introducing compatibility issues for no reason.
- Is the use of Canon lenses intended to be temporary or permanent after switching systems?

  If you plan to continue using your Canon lenses for the foreseeable future, you'd likely be better off with a Canon mirrorless camera. Even though you would still be using an adapter, there would likely be fewer compatibility issues.
- Electronic adapters are not perfect. Expect glitches.

  - Focus may be off. You may have to focus manually.
  - Image stabilization may not work properly. You may need to turn it off.
  - Aperture may be reported inaccurately – an annoyance.
  - Lenses may simply be incompatible (boot loop). You may have to purchase different adapter brands, or even a plain dumb adapter, to be able to use some lenses.